# Delphi : how to preload modules loaded by TOpenDialog?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe2

In my Delphi application, when I execute `TOpenDialog`, it loads a lot of modules before showing the dialog.
This may take a while.(2-3 seconds).
The second and other times, it is much faster.

Is there a way to preload these modules when launching application?

Comment: Indeed, the slow loading of these dialogs is very annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is not that the the modules take a long time to load. The issue is that the Delphi debugger instruments each new module load to report it in the output window.

The slowness you observe the first time the file dialog is shown is an artefact of running under the IDE debugger. If you run your program without the debugger then file dialog initial load time is greatly reduced.

Whilst you could track down the names of the modules that are loading, and force them to be loaded when the process starts, I would absolutely recommend that you do not do that. The modules that are loaded are likely to vary from system to system, so it is entirely possible that if you attempt to do this it will lead to you creating versions of your software that fail to start. Even if you do this just for your private debug builds, you will be guaranteeing that you suffer slower load times every time you debug the program.